# Shuffle Button Stops App When Song Finishes

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

So I have almost finished my project and I need one last bit of help with the shuffle button.

```
     @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp1) {
        try { 
           if(isRepeat == true) {
              mp.start();
           }
           else if(isShuffle == true) {
                mp.reset();
                Random rand = new Random();
                SONG_NUMBER = rand.nextInt((songs.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
                mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));
                mp.start();
           }
            else
            {   
            mp.reset();
            SONG_NUMBER += 1;
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            }
            play.setEnabled(false);
            pause.setEnabled(true);
            stop.setEnabled(true);
            next.setEnabled(true);
            prev.setEnabled(true);
            replay.setEnabled(true);
            shuffle.setEnabled(true);
        } 
        catch(IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }

 }
```

When the shuffle button is clicked, it sets `isShuffle` to `true` but when the song ends, the music player stops completely. Anyone able to help with this?

logcat:

```
10-27 12:00:51.858: W/SignalStrength(724): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:00:51.859: W/SignalStrength(566): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:00:51.859: W/SignalStrength(671): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:00:51.861: W/SignalStrength(671): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:00:51.863: E/ActivityManager(566): Intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIG_STR flg=0x10 (has extras) }mEnablePowerSaverManagerFunction:truesuperMode:false
10-27 12:00:56.979: W/SignalStrength(724): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:00:56.980: W/SignalStrength(566): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:00:56.981: W/SignalStrength(671): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:00:56.983: W/SignalStrength(671): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:00:56.988: E/ActivityManager(566): Intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIG_STR flg=0x10 (has extras) }mEnablePowerSaverManagerFunction:truesuperMode:false
10-27 12:00:57.434: E/ActivityManager(566): Intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) }mEnablePowerSaverManagerFunction:truesuperMode:false
10-27 12:01:00.008: E/ActivityManager(566): Intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x40000014 (has extras) }mEnablePowerSaverManagerFunction:truesuperMode:false
10-27 12:01:02.101: W/SignalStrength(724): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:01:02.102: W/SignalStrength(566): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:01:02.103: W/SignalStrength(671): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:01:02.105: W/SignalStrength(671): getGsmLevel   ro.show.3g.level.by.rscp =  false
10-27 12:01:02.110: E/ActivityManager(566): Intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIG_STR  flg=0x10 (has extras) }mEnablePowerSaverManagerFunction:truesuperMode:false
```

Comment: Can you choose better title for your question?

Comment: post a stack trace from logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mp.reset();
Random rand = new Random();
SONG_NUMBER = rand.nextInt((songs.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));
mp.prepare();   // Try this line
mp.start();
```

I think this is the only difference between the shuffle mode and the normal mode